# Script failing because of indexOf only when triggered (not when tested)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, indexof

I'm playing with Google Apps Script, and I'm getting mad.

The following code is running perfectly, both when clicking the Run and Debug buttons in Google Apps Script site.
But, when trying to execute it by a tyrigger, I always get a strange error :

> TypeError: Fonction indexOf introuvable dans l'objet {year=2020, month=1, day-of-month=8, day-of-week=3, week-of-year=2, hour=17, minute=57, second=56, timezone=UTC, authMode=FULL, triggerUid=2998093}.
>       at createIssueReminder(Code:39)

It's in French, but says `function indexOf not found in object {year=2020, month=1, day-of-month=8, day-of-week=3, week-of-year=2, hour=17, minute=57, second=56, timezone=UTC, authMode=FULL, triggerUid=2998093}`

Here's the odd part: though the message is consistent with itself (well, the object is not an array, so he can't use indexOf), it's totally not consistent with my code as `categories` is an array, and indexOf is called on it. And where the hell am I trying to call indexOf from an instance of a date!?

As said, this piece of code is perfectly working from the Google Apps Script editor, I can't get why or where it's failing when executed by a trigger...

Any insight on this would be highly appreciated.
Thanks all.
You're my only hope, Obi-Wan Kenobi.

```js
/**
 * Check each week if we need a reminder for the week's issue, provided the issue matches the user's chosen categories.
 * @param {string[]} categories The watched categories.
 */
function createIssueReminder(categories) {
  if (!categories)
  {
    categories = ["S", "DD", "D", "M"];
  }
  // Get the "Censored SS Title" spreadsheet
  // cf https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ss-id-here/
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ss-id-here");

  // Get the sheet storing the issues
  var issueSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sorties");

  // Get the range storing the data
  var issueRange = issueSheet.getRange("A2:D81");

  // Get the data from the range
  // use data[row][column] to access values
  var issueData = issueRange.getValues();

  // Get current date and formatted date, in French format Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "CET", "dd/MM/yy")
  var currentDate = new Date();

  var rowIndex = 0;

  for (rowIndex; rowIndex < issueData.length; rowIndex++)
  { // repeat loop until end of data
    var rowDate = issueData[rowIndex][0];

    // if the date in the cell is today's date...
    if (rowDate.getDate() == currentDate.getDate() && 
        rowDate.getMonth() == currentDate.getMonth() && 
        rowDate.getFullYear() == currentDate.getFullYear())
    { 
      // if the issue's category matches any category set for the user...
      if (categories.indexOf(issueData[rowIndex][3]) != -1)
      {
          // add a reminder with the issue number and content
          createIssueReminderEvent(issueData[rowIndex][3], issueData[rowIndex][1], issueData[rowIndex][2]);
      }
    }
  }  
}

/**
 * Add a reminder to the calendar.
 * @param {number} issueNumber The number of the issue.
 * @param {string} issueMessage The content of the issue.
 */
function createIssueReminderEvent(category, issueNumber, issueMessage) {
  // Prepare the message
  var title = "Issue #"+issueNumber+" ["+category+"]"
  var message = issueMessage;
  var timeZone = "CET";
  var now = new Date();
  var startString = Utilities.formatDate(now, timeZone, 'MMMM dd, yyyy 17:30:00 Z');
  var startTime = new Date(startString);
  var endString = Utilities.formatDate(now, timeZone, 'MMMM dd, yyyy 17:35:00 Z');
  var endTime = new Date(endString); 

  // Create event for the issue
  var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, {description: message});

  // Add notification for the event, after deleting default notifications
  event.removeAllReminders();
  event.addPopupReminder(330);

  // Set status (to prevent blocking the day ; workaround as we can't modify transparency of the event)
  // event.addGuest("an-email@goes.here");
  // event.setMyStatus(CalendarApp.GuestStatus.INVITED);

}
```

Comment: sounds like categories is not an array. debug and see what it actually is.

Comment: Consider adding a criteria to validate categories actually is an array, e.g. if `(!categories || !Array.isArray(categories)) . ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you created a trigger on the `createIssueReminder` function. When a trigger calls a function it passes an event object. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events.

So when the trigger calls `createIssueReminder` it passes an event object as `categories`. Your code only sets `categories` if it wasn't passed as an argument.

In the case of a trigger it is passed.

Change your function to this:

```
function createIssueReminder() {
  categories = ["S", "DD", "D", "M"];
...
```